# Selecting row with max value from a subquery, without using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table **films(film, category)**.
I want to find the category with the most films. How do I do that **without using LIMIT?**

I suppose I could do something like this:

```
SELECT category
FROM
(SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM films
GROUP BY category) AS T1
WHERE num =
(SELECT MAX(num)
FROM
(SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM films
GROUP BY category) AS T2)
```

But is there a more elegant way of doing that? Preferably one where I don't have to write the same subquery multiple times?

Thanks!

(And if you're wondering why I can't use LIMIT, it's for homework)

Answer (score 1):

you could do it using a variable to create a row number:

```
SELECT category
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          category
          COUNT(*) as NumOfFiles
          ,(@rn:= @rn + 1) as RowNumber
       FROM
          Films f
          CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) vars
       GROUP BY
          category
       ORDER BY
          COUNT(*) DESC
    ) t
WHERE
    t.RowNumber = 1
```